# Shell debian reduce image size bigger than especific width

Tags: image, shell, resize, debian

Someone knows ifbthere are some option in shell look formimages bigger than a size and reduce them to a maximum size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, use **ImageMagick**. Make a backup first and try on a copy of a few images as this resizes irretrievably!

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -exec mogrify -resize 640x480\> {} \;
```

[Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink)